# Sending Image from silverlight to WCF service

Tags: silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I need to Send Image from silverlight to WCF service.

I try to do it by converting the object WriteableBitmap to byte[] - but the WCF does not have the ability to use WriteableBitmap object ( try to fine the using System.Windows.Media.Imaging but this is not possible )

Is there is some other way to do it ? 
Is there is some Image object that exist in silverlight that can be convert to byte[] and can be use also on the WCF server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Create it by passing the original BitmapSource to the constructor  and then use the Pixels property to get to the bytes.

Comment: But the other side - the WCF side does not have the ability to deserialize the WriteableBitmap object

Comment: Just serialize the bytes and the size and use any class on the server side to recreate the image. In general: do not pass platform specific types when building web services. That will make your service easier to call from other platforms/programming languages.